# Upgrading to ubuntu 19.04: errorr " Could not install 'Install-info' "

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade

During upgrading from 18.10 to 19.04, the error 
Could not install 'Install info'
occured. The upgrade completed. However, when I tried install `cabal`, the following resulted:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package cabal
```

Please assist.

Answer (score 0):

There are many Cabal-related [packages in the repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=disco&searchon=names&keywords=cabal).

As far I can understand you need to install

> **cabal-install**
>   command-line interface for Cabal and Hackage

as it contains `/usr/bin/cabal` (see [search results on packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=cabal&mode=exactfilename&suite=disco&arch=any))

You can install it with

```
sudo apt-get install cabal-install
```